# one div-container produces "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, typeerror, appendchild

I have problem with the following error.

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined"

The meaning of this type of error I already have understand, but I cant explain me what s wrong with my code.

To my project, the idea is a numerical simulation of an orbit from a satellite, I will do an atmospheric model for this. I am using THREE.js for this.

I have a html file with the following code in the body. There is on div-Container with the id "container", which I later want to call in one function. To my mind, the error means that I have to initialize the div-Container. But how it works??? Or what else I'm doing wrong?

> Blockquote

function init() {

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
//var container = document.getElementById('container');
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
document.getElementById("container").body.appendChild( renderer.domElement ); //here we have the error producing line
```

> Blockquote

```
<body>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <div id="container"> //here is the div-container
        <h2 id="titel">Numerische Simulation </h2>
        
        <div id="sliderhoehe">
            <input type="range" id="hoehe" name="hoehe" min="100" max="500" value="300" list="hoehewerte" step="20.0">
            <label for="hoehe">Hoehe in km</label>
            <datalist id="hoehewerte">
                <option value="100" label="100"></option>
                <option value="200" label="200"></option>
                <option value="300" label="300"></option>
                <option value="400" label="400"></option>
                <option value="500" label="500"></option>
            </datalist>

        </div>

          
        <div>
            <input type="range" id="startv" name="startv" min="10000" max="200000" value="28000" list="startvwerte" step="1000">
            <label for="startv">Geschwindikeit in km/h</label>
            <datalist id="startvwerte">
                <option value
            </datalist>
        </div>
        
        <output for="hoehe" id="outputhoehe"></output>
        <button id="stop">Stop</button>
        <button id="start">Start</button>
        <button id="reset">Reset</button>               
        

    </div>
```

I need help. Thank you for answering.

Comment: on init the "container" could be not ready yet, either add the logic on ready or add a callback function to wait for the element to be present then do the append logic

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but the error is thrown because you try to access `appendChild` on the undefined `body` property on the container element. If you want to append renderers DOM element to the container element you would just append straight to it by removing `.body`. Maybe there was confusion because there's a `body` element, which maybe you thought mean something like "the body of the element".

```js
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.getElementById("container").appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r120/three.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
    <div id="container"> //here is the div-container
        <h2 id="titel">Numerische Simulation </h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If I try to take ".body" out of the codeline,than in the browser the sliders doesnt move. I mean the pointer from the slider which is showing to the values of the slider doesnt move.

Comment: Well that's another issue... :)

Comment: ouuuu no but to me it seems like huh we put this from the line away and than it doesnt work so this new problem I have is in some relation to this put the ".body" out...to my mind... because i cannot even look in the console in the browser what the new error is...programming triggers frustration but thanks

Comment: Do you often works with html and maybe also with threejs ? Are the opportunity to send personal messages in stackoverflow?